# No sculping when the other side is hidden

Tags: sculpting, mirror, dynamic-topology

I wanted to model the arms, but I hid the whole body so that I can only see one arm. Unfortunately, the mirror effect is not applied if everything else is hidden. How can I make the mirror effect work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> while in Sculpt Mode to bring up the *Region Clipping* tool. A box can now be drawn to define the area you want to keep visible. Everything else will be hidden. The brush symmetry will still work on the hidden parts.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> again to cancel this mode. Note that it's not always easy to see where the edge of this region is, though you can get a sense of it by orbiting your view. As this tool takes a slice out of the visible area, the affected region actually exists within 3D space, meaning that if you are working up a sculpt, and happen to work your way past one of the clipped boundaries, that part of your sculpt will now fall into a masked region. If this happens, you'll simply need to reuse the tool, and define a new region.